# What does the garbage collector when you have a movieclip into one frame, and your movie is constantly ending and returning to beginning?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, garbage-collection

I already know all the problems in programming based on timeline, but I'm curious to know what happens to garbage collector in that situation.

Talking about code in timeline - as a movieclip isn't accessible if the code isn't in the same frame as it, does this raises the possibility of memory leak?

Seems to me that the movieclips in timeline are added when the "playhead" currently is on it's frame, and removed when it goes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Garbage Collector will not be able to clean/dispose a movie clip removed from stage if:

- that clip is still playing and does stuff (create/remove other things...)
- that clip is still referenced by some other instance that is "reachable"
- you try to remove a way too complicated hierarchy containing too many items [I dont have any number for this, but I'd guess around 2^32 items?]

One way I usually use to see if there is a memory leak is to run SWF Profiler in FlashDevelop and force GC to run at certain situations and see what gets deleted.

Please check following article for more information:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/quick-tip-understanding-garbage-collection-in-as3/

Answer (score 0):

The code is still apart of that MovieClip. So it is still there. And since the MovieClip is ***presumed*** still attached to its parent then it stays.

(I say attached to its parent instead of on screen, because its possible to have parent reference the child, and the child references the parent with the .parent variable, so since they both have something pointing to them, they stay in memory).

Comment: I'm didn't understood, sorry. I'm talking about a movieclip placed on a specific frame in main timeline. If you have a script in other frame, that movieclip is basically unreachable

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I thought this was asking if code was on a certain frame, not a instance of a MovieClip. I don't think I can even hazard a guess at that. Especially if you start dealing with eventListeners and such. Maybe if they were set to weak reference they would eventually vanish. since when you go back to frame 1 again you make a new movieclip instance. But I have personally never made a multi framed movieclip. I've always done everything on 1 frame.

Comment: Me too, but sometimes I see projects done that way. I'm collecting all problems that can show up in that way of programming to use as good reasons for using document classes instead.